# Change a field with a sum value to individual entries

Tags: mysql

I have a table for rating an item.
The field `rating` holds a numeric value that I used to simply increase.
This method has its upsides but the downside is, that I can't have a rating of the past month/30 days because I don't have the individual ratings.

How would I go through the table, check if the `rating`value is higher than `1` and if so add a new line for each rating?

eg
The table now

`id` | `item_id` | `rating`

`1`   | `2198`      | `42`

So I would like to have 42 individual entries.

Question:
**Can I do this with only mysql if so how?**

Comment: why do you need to check if the rating value is higher than 1. when ever there is a rating it could be inserted as new row is not so.

Comment: If the value of `rating`is `2` I would like to create 1 additional entry resulting in 2 entries in total.
if the value of `rating` is `1` I don't need to create anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a stored procedure to do it, but you can do it in mysql.

Since you didn't add your table definitions I will assume `id` is an `auto_increment` key and that you don't want to preserve your original values.
Otherwise change the key or use a new (temporary) table with an auto_increment key.

```
DELIMITER $$

drop PROCEDURE if exists individualizemytable $$ 

CREATE PROCEDURE individualizemytable()
BEGIN
  while (select count(*) from TheTable where rating > 1) do 
    insert into TheTable (item_id, rating)
    select item_id, 1
    from TheTable where rating > 1;
    update TheTable 
    set rating = rating - 1
    where rating > 1;
  end while; 
end $$ 

DELIMITER ;

call individualizemytable();
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `INSERT` for each time rather than `UPDATE` while adding rating to an item. Also use current `timestamp` for the entry.
This will allow you to sum up ratings for an item between two dates easily.

Other but some lengthy solution would be `UPDATE` the rating count each time for an item and add `last modified timestamp`.
While updating, you can compare month from `last modified timestamp` and the current month. If they are the same the you can do `UPDATE` and if they are different, you will do `INSERT`. This way you can have direct count of total ratings for an item for all the months individually.
But again this method will have deep checking like comparing year, also it will impose extra overheads for fetching last modified timestamp every time etc.

Comment: New entries would be saved with `INSERT` but I need to change the old values first.